# backBarButtonItem in navigation controller not showing up

Tags: ios, ios4

I started my xcode project from a NavigationViewController template. And now, when I push a view, that view comes up with an edit button by default and no back bar button. I have commented out the editButton code and the corresponding setEditing delegate method. But I can not get the back button to show up. What am I doing wrong?

Pushing the new view:

```
PlaylistViewController *playlistViewController = [[PlaylistViewController alloc] init];
playlistViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:playlistViewController animated:YES];
[playlistViewController release];
```

in my PlaylistViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"";

    // self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    // doesn't matter if this is here or not
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];
}
```

Comment: I was not able to find out why this was the case. So I deleted the navigation controller from the Interface builder and manually created it with code. Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you tell a UINavigationController to **pushViewController**, it automatically sets the **navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem** to be a button with the title of the previous UIViewController's title.

If no title is set, the default text is "Back".

If the title is set to "", no button will display at all.

```
self.title = @"";
```

Try changing this text and your back button should match the text set here.

Or you can manually override the text of the **leftBarButtonItem** from your new UIViewController.

Comment: feeling awfully lame. Tx.  I had the title set in each view in the initWithNib method. I must have been copy and pasting that self.title line without knowing it... tx.

Comment: Additionally, you can now use navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;